# How to Restrict to edit closed won opportunities

Tags: validation-rule

Hi I have a requirement , where I need to restrict the users to edit closed won opportunities except System admin. How Can I do with Validation Rule? Please can someone help me on this?

Comment: Hi, Does this article helps you.https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000324392&type=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a validation rule as below on Opportunity.

```
AND(
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName),"Closed Won"),
NOT($Profile.Name = "System Administrator")
)
```

Note : User will be able to edit existing Opportunity line items still.